# Nginx subdomain config for Gunicorn server

Tags: nginx, server, configuration, subdomain, gunicorn

I have two servers running on a DigitalOcean droplet. One is a Django/Wagtail application served with Gunicorn (used as a headless CMS), and the other is a SSR Nuxt.js app (front-end). Using the following nginx configuration I’ve made the Nuxt app available at `example.com` (works great), and now I’m trying to make my Django/Wagtail application available at the subdomain `cms.example.com`. (I’ve modified my local hosts file so the domain `example.com` actually functions)

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name cms.example.com;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/thomas/daweb/cms/cms.sock;
    }
}
```

`/etc/nginx/proxy_params`

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Result from `curl --unix-socket /home/thomas/daweb/cms/cms.sock cms.example.com` is html of the default Wagtail landing page, no errors.

However navigating to `cms.example.com` just gives me a connection error. If I swap the two, I can see the Wagtail interface at `example.com`, so I know they’re both working. However, I can’t seem to figure out how to configure a subdomain and I struggle to understand the nginx documentation. Also similar questions about configuring subdomains are usually about making static files available, not listening to active ports.

One extra layer of trouble is that the Wagtail CMS is accessible at `/admin` of its server root, so I’d like to make that page appear at `cms.example.com` rather than having to navigate to `cms.example.com/admin`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Check what is contained in /etc/nginx/proxy_params.  I would expect something like this:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Also, to be sure Gunicorn is working correctly, try:

```
curl --unix-socket /home/thomas/daweb/cms/cms.sock cms.example.com
```

Comment: Yep I've got exactly that, and the curl test delivers the default wagtail page which is good. I'll update my question.

Comment: That's good.  I can't spot any problem with the nginx config (but it's possible that I missed something).  Can you tell where the connection error is coming from? Maybe cms.example.com is not covered by your local DNS change?  Check that, or maybe try adding the IP address to the server_name to see if that makes any difference.